# Format of OnClick link in a .append

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova

I am building a iPhone PhoneGap app, I am trying to include a Share button to share some data I pull from the server using JSON.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
        $.ajax({

        url: 'http://www.myurl.com.au/api/get_category_posts/?category_id=5&custom_fields=displaynative&callback=?',            
        dataType: 'json',
        data: null,
        // crossDomain: true,

        beforeSend : function() {$.mobile.loading('show')},
        complete    : function() {$.mobile.loading('hide')},
        timeout: 15000,

        success: function(data, status)
            {                                          
                (data.portfolio);
                $.each(data.posts, function(i,item){

                if(item.title_plain != undefined){

                          if(item.custom_fields.displaynative != undefined){

$('#datanews').append("<div data-role='collapsible' class='ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon' data-theme='a' data-icon='r'><h4>" + item.title_plain + "</h4><p>"+ item.custom_fields.displaynative +"</p><a href='#' class='ui-btn' onclick=window.plugins.socialsharing.share('" + item.title_plain + "', null, null, '" + item.url + ")'>Save/Share</a></div>").trigger('create');

        }
            }
                        });
```

IT works except the Save/Share button and I know why but i don't know how to fix it.

Needs to be: `Save/Share

But I can't use the "" for the on click because it causes a formatting error.

Anyone know what I can do?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last parenthesis was on the wrong side.

Your code

```
<a href='#' class='ui-btn' onclick=window.plugins.socialsharing.share('" + item.title_plain + "', null, null, '" + item.url + ")'>Save/Share</a>
```

Fixed

```
<a href='#' class='ui-btn' onclick=window.plugins.socialsharing.share('" + item.title_plain + "', null, null, '" + item.url + "')>Save/Share</a>
```

Could also recommend to put double quotes on the `onclick` attribute:

```
<a href='#' class='ui-btn' onclick=\"window.plugins.socialsharing.share('" + item.title_plain + "', null, null, '" + item.url + "'\")>Save/Share</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment greatly appreciate it :)

I've tried `<a href='#' class='ui-btn' onclick=\"window.plugins.socialsharing.share('" + item.title_plain + "', null, null, '" + item.url + "'\">Save/Share</a>` but unfortuently it doesn't work, just doesn't bring up the share window.

FYI I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: Wait it seems to be missing a ) there ... let me see if that works.

Comment: Yes, there was a `)` missing. Thanks for pointing it out. Edited answer.